# How to view resultant group policy of a domain computer?

Tags: group-policy

I have a windows server 2012, with multiple gpo objects created(link order). The gpo are push down to domain computers. my issue is how can i get the resultant group policy of the domain computer? i tried gpresults on the computers and return nothing.(i tried rsop too but no work)

Comment: "(i tried rsop too but no work)" - could you get RSOP to run? And if you did get it to run, what was missing? I just tried it on my domain machine, and it works fine.

Comment: gpsresult not working on my domain pc, when i do a gpresult /h a.html, the html is empty. i checked the group policy 'Turn off resultant logging" is Disabled. i'm using the domain admin account and cmd prompt with admin rights. No errors shown. still couldnt figure out whats wrong.